# Magento header jumping

Tags: php, css, magento

I have strange bug where while browsing through categories on the magento webshop header of the webshop changes height on different pages (http://shop.tvornica-snova.hr/index.php/)

Ie if you are on the homepage, and click on some of the categories the header extends for additinal 10px in height and kind of pushes the content down.

I seem to have same html structure and layout for the both homepage and categories so I cannot figure out where is the bug.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `header-top` section of your markup for a normal page, and for the "jumping" page.

**Normal:**

```
<div class="logo">
    <strong>Magento Commerce</strong>
    <a href="http://shop.tvornica-snova.hr/index.php/" title="Magento Commerce" class="logo">
        <img src="http://shop.tvornica-snova.hr/skin/frontend/default/f002_yellow/images/logotvornica.png" alt="Magento Commerce">
    </a>
</div>
```

**Jumping:**

```
<a href="http://shop.tvornica-snova.hr/index.php/" title="Magento Commerce" class="logo">
    <strong>Magento Commerce</strong>
    <img src="http://shop.tvornica-snova.hr/skin/frontend/default/f002_yellow/images/logotvornica.png" alt="Magento Commerce">
</a>
```

The first one contains two references to `class="logo"`, which has a defined rule of `margin-top: -10px;`. This is the case for any of your pages where the header is the closest to the top of the page - it is being pulled up by `20px`

The second one is marked up slightly differently, and contains just one reference to the class - hence the 10px shift you see.