# Magento header bug

Tags: html, css, magento

I have weird Magento header bug, where the header of the website extends for additional 10px on some of the categories.. 
http://shop.snovotvorci.devpassion.eu/index.php/

If you jump from the homepage on some of the menu navigation items, you'll see that the logo and layout is moved down and that there is additional 10px on the very top of the website.

I cannot to find out why this happens, as I am using same html layout for both homepage and inner pages..

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Didn't you post this exact same issue yesterday? Did my answer not help? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15374446/magento-header-jumping/15375649#15375649](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15374446/magento-header-jumping/15375649#15375649)

Comment: No, the reason is not that std div :-) 

I also removed all unnecassry things from the layout of the header and the content, and the bug stays there. 

Pretty weird, I cannot figure out wheres the problem. 

Thanks for your help anyhow..

Answer (score 0):

The bug was in header.phtml file.

There is a php sytax overthere saying something like ifhomepage echo this logo, and else echo this logo. And basically there are same logos but in first case on the homepage there is additioal div causing that bug.

Cheers